# How to make LaTeX compilation portable

Tags: compiling

What can I do to make the compilation of a PDF file in Latex portable?

I understand 'portable' in the sense that the same source files produce the same PDF file.

The purpose is to verify that a particular source file (or a huge bulk thereof) produces a certain PDF document. People should be able to verify that on their own computer.

For example, I do not whether environment conditions (compilation date, absolute paths, etc.) are invisibly included in the tex-file.

Comment: Have you tried? Compiling a document twice and comparing the two pdfs gives `Binary files differ`; so yes, even something like the compilation date is included. Even if you find options to avoid this, you will have to build a mini-TeX-distribution including all fonts, configuration files and even `pdflatex` binaries (or whatever program you use), which will bind you to a particular platform. So my guess is that it is not really possible to provide all the ingredients such that everyone gets the same bits in the pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very little *information* about your TeX system is placed in the PDF: much more likely to influence outcomes is variations in the code available. There is a small amount of meta-data in the PDF, for example the pdfTeX version, date of compilation, *etc.* This can all be suppressed using appropriate primitives: several supporting ideas have been added to pdfTeX/XeTeX in recent years for 'reproducible build' tests.

The LaTeX team have an interest in testing and the framework is available as [`l3build`](http://ctan.org/pkg/l3build). Whilst this is probably most focussed on testing using the `.log` file, it can also be used for PDF-based comparisons. (In general, if the `\showoutput` trace of a file is unchanged then this shows the TeX code is 'doing it's job', though PDF identity is dependent on for example font files.)

Comment: I presume with 'code available' you refer to the implementation of the system and the package versions, etc. - right?